# Arrange plots created by descdist

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently using `par(mfrow = c(i,j))` to arrange multiple plots in my project. However I am stuck when I try to achieve the same thing with plots produced by a function.

More specifically  the `descdist()` function which produces a plot (as well as a console output). The codesnippet below executes, but it does not bring the desired result, since it produces two seperate figures. Please note that on the first picture the `par` did "its thing" since there is room on the right side for the second plot.

````
# Title

```{r}
library(fitdistrplus)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
descdist(x, discrete = FALSE)
plot(y)
```
````

[image]

In this mock-up example it does not really matter what `x` and `y` are since individually the plots are fine. Also I feel like it is not a problem specifically arising by using the `descdist` function but rather a general question how to handle and adress plots produced by functions.

Is there an easy workaround to fix this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more context (e.g., data, libraries)?

Comment: This part of the r-markdown cookbook should get you covered: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figures-side.html